# Javascript timer read interval from input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input of type text where I add a value.

```
<input type="text" name="mydat" id="mydat" value="60000" />
```

This I have a timer which runs every minute.

```
<script>

window.setInterval(function(){

 //do something here

}, 60000);

</script>
```

In the code above the interval value is hardcoded.

How can I do this instead:

60000 = #mydat value

So, everytime it loops it reads the value from #mydat ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the value of an input using the value attribute.

```
var interval = document.getElementById('mydat').value;

window.setInterval(function() {
    // Some code...
}, interval);
```

or using jQuery

```
var $interval = $('#mydat').val();

window.setInterval(function() {
    // Some code...
}, $interval);
```

Comment: Note that this will read the value from `mydat` on the first iteration; when the user types a different number, it won't adjust the interval.

Comment: This seems odd, you asked `How can I do this instead... so everytime it loops it reads the value from #mydat` This answer does not do that. As `dbaseman` pointed out, it only reads it ones not everytime.

Answer (score 7):

Use `setTimeout` recursively instead.

```
var startTimer = function() {
    console.log("do something here");
    window.setTimeout(startTimer, parseInt($("#mydat").val(), 10));
});

startTimer();
```

Comment: +1 nice and clean, but don't forget about `.val()` and the `radix` parameter

Answer (score 5):

"Every time it loops" implies that the value might change - so `setInterval` is incorrect, you'd need to use `setTimeout` repeatedly...

```
function DoSomething() {
    //Do Stuff
    setTimeout(DoSomething, document.getElementById('mydat').value);
}
```

should do what you need and update the timeout if the contents of the textbox changes (after the next event fires)